# Exercise 20 of Zed Shaw's Learn Python 3 The Hard Way. str object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python

I have been trying to execute exercise 20 from Zed Shaw's book "Learn Python 3 The Hard Way". I always recieve a message that the str object has no attribute 'read'. The purpose of the exercise is to read the content of files together and separately in lines with the aid of functions. How do I fix this?

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import *

script, input_file = argv


def print_all(f):
    print(f.read())


def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)


def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print(line_count, f.readline())


current_file = open(input_file)

print("First let's print the whole file\n")

print_all(current_file)

print("Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.")

rewind(current_file)

print_all("Let's print three lines:")

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

The code should recieve this as output

```
$ python ex20.py test.txt
First let's print the whole file:

This is line 1
This is line 2
This line 3

Now let's rewind, kind of like a tapea.
Let's print three lines:
1 This is line 1

2 This  is line 2 

3 This is line 3
```

Comment: What is the output you see? I dont see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: FYI: https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Comment: This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line3.
Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rayan\Desktop\everything_python\ex20.py", line 29, in <module>
    print_all("Let's print three lines:")
  File "C:\Users\rayan\Desktop\everything_python\ex20.py", line 8, in print_all
    print(f.read())
          ^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 2):

on line 29:

```
print_all("Let's print three lines:")
```

should be replaced with:

```
print("Let's print three lines:")
```

as the function `print_all()` expects a file object

Comment: Great! It is also good practice to use `current_file.close()` at the end of your program.